# What is the equivalent of "scare quote"?

Tags: phrase-request

In English, *scare quote* is used for those words or phrases put in quotes, where they aren't used for their literal meaning, as in the following sentence.

> That was really a "smart" move.

Is there an equivalent expression for the Italian? Google Translate gives *virgolette* as translation, but that does apply also for a normal quote.
I know that, speaking, I could say *tra virgolette* to mean I am using the word to mean the opposite.

> Quella era, tra virgolette, una mossa brillante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non mi risulta un nome specifico, ma per esempio nell'[Enciclopedia dell'Italiano](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/virgolette_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/) Treccani, descrivendo questa, fra le varie funzioni delle virgolette, si dice che sono una marca *di distanziamento*.

> Ha funzione **di distanziamento** la coppia di virgolette ... usata per contrassegnare un’espressione non ritenuta appropriata perché di uso settoriale, gergale o dialettale, e **di cui è richiesta un’interpretazione ironica, allusiva o in generale di tipo traslato**:
>
> (4) Nel 1986 le manifestazioni studentesche di massa costringono il governo del gollista Chirac a ritirare la legge sulla selezione per l’ingresso all’università. Nel 1991 è sufficiente qualche dimostrazione per convincere il socialista Jospin a lasciar cadere la «sua» riforma universitaria (Antonio Caprarica, *Com’è dolce Parigi ... o no!?*, Milano, Sperling & Kupfer, 2007, p. 58)
>
> È stato notato come di questo tipo di virgoletta, nella lingua scritta contemporanea, si faccia spesso abuso, con il rischio di trasmettere un’impressione di scarsa competenza (Serianni 2003: 57).

(grassetti miei)

Anche Serianni (*Italiano*, I, 207, non lo stesso testo citato qui su) parla della funzione di «segnalare la presa di distanza dello scrivente» ed esemplifica con un testo giornalistico in cui a proposito di un fatto di cronaca si parla di “prova della verità” e “compare traditore”, e ovviamente l'autrice non abbracciava questa interpretazione dei fatti.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, When **speaking** you can say:
- Quella era, tra virgolette, una mossa brillante
or
- Quella era, per così dire, una mossa brillante

When **writing** you can use quotation marks, just like in English
-Quella era una mossa "brillante".

Comment: But these are some of the ways, so to say, to “implement” the scare quotes, not to name them in Italian.

Comment: @DaG is correct: I am asking how scare quotes are called in Italian.